# Is the UserId in LVL responses unique?

Tags: android, google-play, userid

I am using Googles Licensing in my apps and I wonder if the UserId that is part of the license answer from the market is unique to the user?

Comment: Duplicate Q?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6599425/application-licensing-and-android-unique-id

Comment: I know Google uses IDs, but are they unique? Is it possible that two users have the same UserId in that LVL license response?

Comment: If it works as with e.g Facebook that UID would originate from a database which requires it by definition to be primary and unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it finally in a Javadoc comment in `DeviceLimiter.java`:

> The LICENSED response from the server contains a user identifier unique to
>   the <application, user> pair.

They say it's unique. Congratulations. Please decide whether believe or not :)

Comment: Actually it is not <application, user> pair, just user.

Comment: My testing shows it's unique to application/user. Same user, different apps  => different UserIDs.